# DevExpress XtraGrid FocusedRowChanged event problem when changing datasource

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

This problem has bugged me for several years and maybe someone here knows a simple solution, since I just ran into it again.

QUESTION: Is there any way to get the XtraGrid to "forget" the current focused row index before a new (different) datasource is assigned to the grid?

BACKGROUND
We use the XtraGrid as a kind of controller for what is displayed in another panel of a multipane Winform.

Now imagine a hypothetical scenario where the datasource of the XtraGrid keeps changing according to menu selections. Menu item 1 populates the grid with a list of today's entrees in the cafeteria: Id, Name. Menu item 2 populates the grid with a list of Customers the user must phone that day: ID, Name. Important thing is that these are separate distinct datasources, and the grid's datasource is being assigned and reassigned.

CRITICAL FACT FOR THIS QUESTION:
We want the grid's FocusedRowChanged event to be **the single place**  where we trap the user's selection in the controller grid. We are a "no spaghetti code" shop. FocusedRowChanged is better than a click event because it handles keyboard navigation too. The row with the focus contains the ID of the detail record we need to fetch from the database for display in Panel #2.  This works--*most of the time*.

Here's how it doesn't work: let's say that on a given day, the list of customers the user must contact contains only one row. So the first (and only) row in the grid is the focused row. Now let's say that the user goes up to the menu and selects the menu item to display the day's cafeteria entrees. When the user clicks on the first item in the Entrees list, the FocusedRowChanged event does NOT fire because the grid has retained a memory of the focused row index from the previous datasource. The focused row *index* has not changed.  And thus the user's selection doesn't trigger anything.

I tried to get DevExpress to offer a second more row-object-oriented mode (as distinct from row-index-oriented approach) whereby each row in the grid would have a GUID, and the FocusedRowChanged event would fire whenever the GUID of the currently focused row differed from the GUID of the previously focused row, regardless of whether the focused row index happened to be the same. This would allow dynamic changes of datasource and enable the desired behavior. But they demurred.

So I'll ask my question again, Is there any way to get the XtraGrid to "forget" the current focused row index before a new datasource is assigned to the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best solution to this problem is to create a new GridView object and override its DoChangeFocusedRowInternal method.  Below you will find the default implementation of this method.  All you need to do is to change the marked row just as your needs dictate.  Also, take a look at the [How to create a GridView descendant class and register it for design-time use](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A859.aspx) article, it contains some useful information.

```
public class MyGridView : GridView {
        protected override void DoChangeFocusedRowInternal(int newRowHandle, bool updateCurrentRow) {
            if(this.lockFocusedRowChange != 0) return;
            if(!IsValidRowHandle(newRowHandle))
                newRowHandle = DevExpress.Data.DataController.InvalidRow;
            if(FocusedRowHandle == newRowHandle) return; // <<<<<<
            int currentRowHandle = FocusedRowHandle;
            BeginLockFocusedRowChange();
            try {
                DoChangeFocusedRow(FocusedRowHandle, newRowHandle, updateCurrentRow);
            }
            finally {
                EndLockFocusedRowChange();
            }
            RaiseFocusedRowChanged(currentRowHandle, newRowHandle);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

My code:

```
namespace MyXtraGrid {

        public class MyGridControl : GridControl {
            protected override BaseView CreateDefaultView() {
                return CreateView("MyGridView");
            }
            protected override void RegisterAvailableViewsCore(InfoCollection collection) {
                base.RegisterAvailableViewsCore(collection);
                collection.Add(new MyGridViewInfoRegistrator());
            }
        }

        public class MyGridViewInfoRegistrator : GridInfoRegistrator {
            public override string ViewName { get { return "MyGridView"; } }
            public override BaseView CreateView(GridControl grid) {
                return new MyGridView(grid as GridControl);
            }
        }
        public class MyGridView : GridView {
            public MyGridView(GridControl ownerGrid) : base(ownerGrid) { }
            public MyGridView() { }


            protected virtual bool RowEqual(int focusedRowHandle, int newRowHandle) {
                if(IsDesignMode)
                    return focusedRowHandle == newRowHandle;
                DataRow row1 = GetDataRow(focusedRowHandle);
                DataRow row2 = GetDataRow(newRowHandle);
                return row1 == row2;
            }

            protected override void DoChangeFocusedRowInternal(int newRowHandle, bool updateCurrentRow) {
                if(this.lockFocusedRowChange != 0) return;
                if(!IsValidRowHandle(newRowHandle))
                    newRowHandle = DevExpress.Data.DataController.InvalidRow;
                if(RowEqual(FocusedRowHandle, newRowHandle))
                    return;
                int currentRowHandle = FocusedRowHandle;
                BeginLockFocusedRowChange();
                try {
                    DoChangeFocusedRow(FocusedRowHandle, newRowHandle, updateCurrentRow);
                }
                finally {
                    EndLockFocusedRowChange();
                }
                RaiseFocusedRowChanged(currentRowHandle, newRowHandle);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I follow the instructions from the KB article, I can enter the DoChangeFocusedRowInternal event (see above) in the debugger and step through the code.  But my grid is never visually rendered.  What am I missing?

Comment: And when I try to drop MyGrid (inheriting as per KB) from the ToolBox onto the form, VS2010 crashes. I wish DevExpress could just invoke that little optimization (FocusedRowHandle==newRowHandle) return;) by default unless it's turned off using some design-time property the developer could set when datasources are going to be changed, as per the original question.

Comment: I do not know the code you are using so I cannot comment on it.  anyway, I've updated my answer with all required classes.  I hope, it will help you.

Comment: Changes do permit the derived control to be dropped onto the form. But code in RowEqual method doesn't work (and logically CANNOT work) because focusedRowHandle is 0 and newRowHandle is also 0, and so the GetDataRow() method must return the SAME row.  Remember, the original data source has been replaced with a new one, and at this point in the code you can only reference the row from the CURRENT data source. There needs to be something like a RowGUID in addition to the (int) RowHandle.

Comment: @Tim, my code is just a sample on how this feature can be implemented. You know the task better and thus if this code works, there should not be a problem to modify it per your requirements...

Comment: I think you're washing your hands of the matter. This is a limitation of the grid's design. *Within the scope of the DoChangeFocusedRowInternal method*, it is impossible to know that FocusedRowHandle points at a row that belonged to the previous datasource. When these handles both contain the same value, i.e. 0, the FocusedRowChanged event must fire IF the datasource has changed.  If you instantiate two datasources each with one row and alternately assign these datasources to the grid, there is no clean way to use the FocusedRowChanged event because the focused row handle never changes.

Comment: There needs to be a way to know (within the scope of the DoChangeFocusedRowInternal method and not using some cheezy global variable) that FocusedRowHandle and newRowHandle are pointing at rows that belong to totally different datasources. Either that, or instead of integer row handles the row handles need to be GUIDs.

Comment: Actually, I just wanted you to show the best possible way of how to implement the required functionality yourself with less efforts.  It seems to me, creating a derived control is the best solution.  Finally, please note that the GridControl also provides the DataSourceChanged event.  May be this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have found the method which should work for you ideally  - OnCurrentControllerRowObjectChanged.  It is protected virtual in the BaseView class.  So, all you need to do is to create a derived View and use your code in this method.  It should be executed only when a datarecord object is changed ...

Comment: Thanks for this additional info. I will try it out!

Answer (score 3):

Tim, I had the exact same problem when the grid only had one row of data in it and then changed data sources. I solved it by setting the gridview.FocusedRowHandle = -1 after setting the new datasource.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation, I am subscribing to the

`FocusedRowObjectChanged`

event (using DevExpress 16.1).

Comment: Another reason for us to upgrade. This will help me make the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe on the DataSourceChanged event which will fire when Data source changes (you guessed it!) so then you can get using GetFocusedObject() the object and display the relevant items for the other grid...

Comment: Yes, but DataSourceChanged leads to spaghetti. The point is to be able to do this in ONE place, in ONE way.  <<K.I.S.S.>> I want to ask this simple question: "Am I looking at a different row?" DevExpress asks this more complicated question: "Does this row occupy a different position in the array?" Since the underlying datasource can change, using array position as an indicator of sameness/difference is not as good as using something INTRINSIC to  the row object, like a row GUID.